# Building indexes in MongoDB with .NET driver 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

What's the new way to build indexes with the new driver 2.0?
There's no documentation whatsoever about this.

Apparently this now works with the new `IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<>` interface but that's all I got so far.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after upgrading to 2.0! Why did they feel the need to absolute overcomplicate something that was simple!?

Comment: I am starting to like it. I can see where the design decisions came from and the usage of builders in this case is consistent with other usages (filter builders, etc). I especially like that they have made everything fully async. It's just (currently at least) not well documented and not easy to get detailed information or samples.

Comment: It's been a couple of days and I'm liking it too, especially the async stuff.  It was so many changes with very little documentation that frustrated me, I had to resort to reading the source on github... I'm sure they'll resolve that soon though

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to call and `await` `CreateOneAsync` with an `IndexKeysDefinition` you get by using `Builders.IndexKeys`:

```
static async Task CreateIndex()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("db");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Hamster>("collection");
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Name));
}
```

If you don't have a `Hamster` you can also create the index in a non-strongly-typed way by specifying the index's json representation:

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync("{ Name: 1 }");
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do it for BsonDocument collections?

Comment: @BigJoe714 I've updated the post. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How to create multiple indexes by using Indexes.CreateMany()?